# RxJS mergeMap wait for inner Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a solution which first seemed to work, but then I tried it with slow network:

```js
public getKeyFigureValuesForAllClients(keyFigurename: string) {

    const keyFigureDefintion$ = this.keyFigureDefintions$.pipe(
      flatMap((keyFigure) => keyFigure),
      filter((x) => x.name === keyFigurename),
      take(1));

    const clients$ = this.dataService.getClients().pipe(
      flatMap((client) => client));

    const keyFigureAndClients$ = combineLatest([keyFigureDefintion$, clients$]);
    return keyFigureAndClients$.pipe(
      tap(x=>console.log(x)),
      switchMap(([keyfigure, client]) =>

        this.dataService.getDataPointsByPeriodName(client.id, this.currentPeriodName).pipe(
          map((datapoints) => ({
              client,
              datapoints,
              keyFigureCalculator: new KeyFigureCalculator(keyfigure, datapoints),
            }),
          )),
      ),
      tap(x=>console.log(x)),
      toArray(),
    );
  }
```

So first I load my keyfigure and a list of clients. Then I want to get the corresponding datapoints and return an array with all my values.
But it seems that the `this.dataService.getDataPointsByPeriodName()` takes a little bit longer, so i only get the values for the first client. If I change the network speed to "online" in Chrome everything works (9 out of 10 tries...).

Is there any wait operator? I found something about concatAll(), but I don't know where to place it and how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly it is a little bit weird, that you flat a stream of client "just" to use `toArray()` again later. Maybe somewhere in this approach is the reason for the described behavior, but I can't say for sure. Please find below a suggestion without `flatMap`

```
public getKeyFigureValuesForAllClients(keyFigurename: string) {

    const keyFigureDefintion$ = this.keyFigureDefintions$.pipe(
      map(keyFigures => keyFigures.find(keyFigure => keyFigure.name === keyFigurename)),
    )
    const clients$ = this.dataService.getClients();

    const keyFigureAndClients$ = forkJoin([keyFigureDefintion$, clients$]).pipe(    
      switchMap(([keyfigure, clients]) => {       
        return forkJoin(clients.map(client => this.dataService.getDataPointsByPeriodName(client.id, this.currentPeriodName).pipe(
          map((datapoints) => ({
              client,
              datapoints,
              keyFigureCalculator: new KeyFigureCalculator(keyfigure, datapoints),
            }),
          ))));
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Wow ur my hero! Thank u so much! This observable stuff drives me crazy!
Honestly, I don't know why i used the "toArray()" operator. It worked, so I was happy...
Grüße nach München aus Nürnberg ;-)